Serializer not returning expected output in .NET Core
I have a controller which returns Task<ActionResult> which internally returns a List<CustomObjectA>.
The structure of CustomObjectA is like this:
[DataContract]
public class CustomObjectA
{
    public CustomObjectA(){}

    [DataMember]
    public CustomObjectB Member1 {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public List<CustomObjectC> Member2 {get; set;} = null;
}

Controller looks like this:
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Get(ODataQueryOptions<CustomObjectA> options)
{
    try
    {
        List<CustomObjectA> results = await _service.Get(options);

        // Log the results
        Logger.log($"{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results)}");
        Logger.Log($"{JsonConvert.SerializeObject((Ok(results)).Value)}");

        return Ok(results);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}

I am not getting null values for the Member2 of CustomObjectA whenever it is set to null in the code, but it is getting returned as an empty list.
Output:
[
    {
        "Member1": ...,
        "Member2": [
            {
                "Property1": "Value1",
                "Property2": "Value2"
            },...
        ]
    },
    {
        "Member1": ...,
        "Member2": []
    }
]

whereas the log lines output the values as:
[
    { "Member1": ..., 
      "Member2": [  
                     { "Property1": "Value1", 
                       "Property2": "Value2" 
                     },
                     ...
                 ] 
    }, 
    { "Member1": ..., 
      "Member2": null 
    } 
]

In my Startup.cs, I have added
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson()

Can someone help here? I am not sure how do I determine what serialization is used by the controller. If any steps for that are present, that would be helpful too. Thanks.

I can't reproduce this in a standalone app, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qeh4xT.  Could you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?

Just a guess here, but in startup could you be configuring your JsonSerializerOptions with a converter or type info resolver modifier that outputs [] for null collections?  A [mcve] would clarify thanks.

Let me check the JsonSerializerOptions thing. I will see how can I generate the MRE. I dont know how to determine the serializer it is using. Although the AddNewtonsoftJson() is added in Startup.cs, but logger outputs what your fiddle shows, but not the response of the curl in powershell.

Well could you share the relevant startup code?  Json.NET also does not serialize a null list as an empty array so one way or another something must be happening that is not shown in your question.   I dont know how to determine the serializer it is using. -- System.Text.Json ignores data member attributes while Json.NET respects them so you could add say [DataMember(Name="I-Was-Serialized-Using-Newtonsoft-Json")] to Member1 to see which serializer is being used, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qeh4xT

What does your await _service.Get(options);  returning? Could you please share the details?
